# web component packaging Settings

Tags: css, vue.js, web-component, font-face, vue-cli

How do I set the web component in vue.config.js and extract a separate section of iconfont.css when packaging

I run the

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc-async --name chat-ui src/views/Chat/Launcher.vue --report
```

command to package the web component, how to set the specific Settings in vue.config.js

Answer (score 0):

With me, I set the specific settings in `vue.config.js` for packaging a web component and extracting a separate section of iconfont.css, you can make use of the configureWebpack option. Here's an example of how you can achieve that:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
configureWebpack: (config) => {

// Add additional webpack configuration
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

// Configuration for production build
// Extract a separate section of iconfont.css
  config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.styles = {
    name: 'iconfont',
    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*iconfont\.css$/,
    chunks: 'all',
    enforce: true,
  };
}
},
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but this configuration doesn't seem to work for packaging web compoent